# Copy certain cells from a row below when 2 conditions are both met

Tags: vba, excel

I'm really new to VBA and I only get by with copying codes from solutions on this site but for this one I can't find a similar problem.

I want to copy only certain cells (not whole rows) when column A and B aligns as "apple" with "cat". I also want to delete that row I copied from.

[the plan illustrated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FI3Ei.png)

My code so far:

```
Sub animals() 
Dim rcnt As Long
rcnt = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To rcnt
    If Range("B" & i).Value = "cat" And ("A" & i) = "apple" Then
        Range("C" & i).Offset(1, 0).Copy
        Range("D" & i).Offset(1, 0).Copy
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Code looks reasonable but you have provided no destination once you have copied the cell(s). The destination is similarly omitted from your narrative.

Comment: Hi! I just want to copy the bottom cell C and D upwards I thought the 'offset' should do that?

Comment: So in your example, you're wanting to copy "elephant // snake" up to the "apple // cat" row?  Also, is this **exactly** as your code is in VBA? AFAIK, the `And` line should be on the same as the other, ie `If Range("B" & i).Value = "cat" And ("A" & i) = "apple" Then`

Comment: Hi! Yes, I want to copy elephant/snake upwards to replace dog/fish. I edited the code to bring up the And statement. However it still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
For i = 1 To rcnt
    If Range("B" & i).value = "cat" And ("A" & i) = "apple" Then
        Range("C" & i).value = Range("C" & i).Offset(1, 0).value
        Range("D" & i).value = Range("D" & i).Offset(1, 0).value
    End If
Next i
```

You were copying the data, just not pasting it anywhere. This method will skip the `.Copy` (skipping the clipboard), and just sets the values equal.

Comment: Even after correcting: `If Range("B" & i).value = "cat" And ("A" & i) = "apple" Then` to `If Range("B" & i).value = "cat" And ("A" & i).Value = "apple"`  it still does not work. It really looked like it would work though.